# POST activity with special characters in Direct Line

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, ansi, iso

***TLDR at the end***

Currently I need to POST an `Activity` to the `DirectLine` sending a message with a special character, the string is `Menú principal`, please notice the **`ú`**. Everything else works fine but sending special characters makes me cry.

But when I am sending the serialized activity, it displays a `?`, so as you can see `Menú principal != Men? principal` which wil make the bot to answer different.

I've tried a few things but it doesn't seem to work, this is my current function to POST.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Uploads to an URL and gets result
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of object you are receiving</typeparam>
    /// <param name="bearer">Token</param>
    /// <param name="url">Url</param>
    /// <param name="serializedJson">Serialized JSON to send</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T uploadString<T>(string bearer, string url, string serializedJson)
    {
        string serializedResult = "";

        /// Webclient
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            /// Looks like it goes wrong when uplading UTF8 words
            string ansistring = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serializedJson));

            try
            {
                /// Add headers
                client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
                client.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {bearer}");

                /// Upload string
                serializedResult = client.UploadString(url, ansistring);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string a = e.Message;
            }
        }

        /// Get result and return it as an object
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedResult);
    }
```

The parameter `serializedJson` is an `Activity` object serialized using Json.NET and it looks like this when I am trying to send `Menú principal`.

`serializedJson = "{\"type\":\"message\",\"id\":\"c5908d50-5389-11e8-bd5c-45bb8f0ca339\",\"timestamp\":\"2018-05-09T13:06:22.49+00:00\",\"localTimestamp\":null,\"serviceUrl\":null,\"channelId\":null,\"from\":{\"id\":\"default-user\",\"name\":\"User\"},\"conversation\":null,\"recipient\":null,\"textFormat\":\"plain\",\"attachmentLayout\":null,\"membersAdded\":null,\"membersRemoved\":null,\"reactionsAdded\":null,\"reactionsRemoved\":null,\"topicName\":null,\"historyDisclosed\":null,\"locale\":\"es\",\"text\":\"Menú principal\",\"speak\":null,\"inputHint\":null,\"summary\":null,\"suggestedActions\":null,\"attachments\":[],\"entities\":[],\"channelData\":{\"clientActivityId\":\"1525870846394.1792692356311325.10\"},\"action\":null,\"replyToId\":null,\"value\":null,\"name\":null,\"relatesTo\":null,\"code\":null,\"expiration\":null,\"importance\":null,\"deliveryMode\":null,\"textHighlights\":null}"`

As you can see the `text` is `"text\":\"Menú principal\"`.

After seeing the Activity log in the conversation, it displays the `ú` as a `?`.

[image: https://gyazo.com/ff1fa7045de11ab0a5d721bc198363c0]

You can find the entire code in [this](https://github.com/emimontesdeoca/integration-test-directline-bot-framework) repository, the `uploadString` function is in [this](https://github.com/emimontesdeoca/integration-test-directline-bot-framework/blob/master/src/IntegrationTestBotFramework/Utils/Utils.cs) class and the test cases are in [this](https://github.com/emimontesdeoca/integration-test-directline-bot-framework/blob/master/src/IntegrationTestBotFramework/IntegrationTest.cs) file.

**TLDR: I need to send `Menú principal` to DirectLine and when it reachs the bot it displays like this: `Men? principal`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That character is not a valid ASCII character.  Try using Unicode encoding for your string:

```
var stringToSend = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Menú principal"));
```

Comment: Your answer was not working but helped me to get it working, the solution was to get the UTF8 bytes and the convert it to ANSI, thanks Eric as always!

Comment: I would love to see how you did that